# Visual Studio Visualizer

Tags: c#, runtime, code-injection

To make this clear, I'm using .net 3.5

I'm currently creating an Visual Studio Visualizer in order to be able to see the values of individual rules in a WF RuleSet. Everything is ok, but now I need to do the following.

Let's say I have a rule which is "this.Age > 50" and one then action as MessageBox.Show("Bigger than 50") and one else action as MessageBox.Show("Less than 50")

I need to be able to select the rule "this.Age > 50" and evaluate it as true or false. Or I need to select part of the rule, eg. "this.Age" and evaluate it to let's say 70.

This last bit is working. I'm getting the object in which the RuleSet executes and getting the fileds and try to find one field named Age and if I do find, I get it's value, on the event of not finding the field I then look at properties. This is working.

The problem is evaluating "this.Age > 50". Of course, I could do a parser in this case and evaluate it, but the problem is then I would have to evaluate "this.Age > 50", "this.Age < 50"... I guess you understand the problem. And of course I also want to evaluate for example, "this.GetCurrentAge()", in which GetCurrentAge() is a method in the class represented by the object in which context the RuleSet executes.

I've thought I could try to inject a method at runtime into the object I currently have and which is instantiated. This way, I could create something as simples as

```
public string EvaluationMethod()
{
return (this.Age > 50).ToString();
}
```

in this case, I would at runtime build this method and inject it in the current instance of object.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to inject code into the current instance of the object. I can only find examples on how to create new classes at runtime, but nothing about only creating a method and inject it.

Can someone please help, or give any other idea?

Thanks